# Why can views::reverse transform a non-sized_range into a size_range?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

In [[range.sized#1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.sized#1):

> The `sized_­range` concept refines range with the requirement that the
> number of elements in the range can be determined in **amortized**
> **constant time** using `ranges​::​size`.
>
> ```
> template<class T>   
>   concept sized_­range =
>   range<T> &&
>     requires(T& t) { ranges::size(t); };
> ```

The standard states that obtaining the size of [`ranges::sized_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/sized_range) **is guaranteed to be in constant time**. Consider the following:

```
auto r1 = std::views::iota(0)
    | std::views::filter([](int x){ return x % 2 == 0; })
    | std::views::take(1'000'000);
```

`r1` is obviously not `sized_range`, because it is impossible to get its size in
constant time, which also means that we use `ranges::size` to evaluate its size is also ill-formed.

But I discovered by accident that if we apply [`views::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view) on it, the new range `r2` suddenly becomes a `sized_range`, and we can directly use `ranges::size` to get its size correctly, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fb314x316):

```
auto r2 = r1 | views::reverse;

static_assert(!ranges::sized_range<decltype(r1)>);
static_assert( ranges::sized_range<decltype(r2)>);
std::cout << std::ranges::size(r2) << "\n"; // print 500'000
```

However, it is obvious that the new range `r2` is not a `sized_range`, since we can never get its size in constant time, this seems to violate what the standard says.

Why can `views::reverse` transform a non-`sized_range` into a `sized_range`? Obviously, this conversion will not have any effect on the size of the original range. Is this a standard defect or is it a library bug?

Comment: Note that `r2.size()` does fail with `candidate: 'constexpr auto std::ranges::reverse_view<_Vp>::size() requires  sized_range<_Vp>`.

Comment: "amortized" is doing a lot of work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirement is *amortized* constant, not always constant.

- `take_view<...>` produces `counted_iterator`s.
- So `reverse_view<take_view<...>>` produces `reverse_iterator<counted_iterator<...>>`
- `counted_iterator`s can always be subtracted: you just subtract the count.
- So `reverse_iterator<counted_iterator<...>>` can always be subtracted too.
- `ranges::size` is defined for any range whose iterator/sentinel models `sized_sentinel_for`. That includes `reverse_view<take_view<...>>`.

To meet the amortized constant complexity requirement, `reverse_view::begin` caches the end of the source range if it needs to compute it (i.e., the source range isn't common).